# SPUtility not work in SP2016 survey

Tags: jquery, 2016, survey, sputility

I am trying to customize a survey form using SPUtility. My survey form only have 1 field named "Event". I tried to pre-fill the field "Event" but in console it is returning: `Unable to get a SPField named Event`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/sputility.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/survey.js"></script>
```

In my survey.js it is very simple:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
SPUtility.GetSPField('Event').MakeReadOnly();
SPUtility.GetSPField('Event').SetValue('Training session 1');
}
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

From your code, you are marking the 'Event' field as read-only first and then updating it.

Kindly set the value first and then mark the field as read-only.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     SPUtility.GetSPField('Event').SetValue('Training session 1');
     SPUtility.GetSPField('Event').MakeReadOnly();
}
```

OR

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     SPUtility.GetSPField('Event').SetValue('Training session 1').MakeReadOnly();
}
```

In `GetSPField()` method, you need to pass the Display Name of the field.

Comment: By using `$("input[Title='Event']").val("CPMWS Training session 1");` it is working. But `SPUtility.GetSPField('Event').SetValue('Training session 1');` still throw me error "Unable to get a SPField named Event". Is it because SPUtility only work in older version of JQuery v1.x?

Answer (score 0):

While using `SPUtility.GetSPField()` function, you need to use the **Display Name** of your SharePoint field.

Try using the display name of field, it should work for you.